# Is it safe to have asprintf use a non-NULL target pointer that is also a input?

Tags: c, alias, stdio

**tl;dr** Can `asprintf` be used naively for concatenation without invoking a temporary pointer?

---

The function `asprintf` introduced by GNU and adopted in several other clib implementations is a tempting solution for arbitrary concatenation in c using a scheme like

```
int i=0;
char *str = strdup(argv[i]);
while (argv[++i]) {
   asprintf(&str,"%s %s",argv[i],str);   // <=== This line
}
asprintf(&str,"%s\n",str);
```

When wrapped in a main and the necessary includes, this runs fine for me.

### But...

Is it leaking memory all over the place? Valgrind says it is on my box. Is this a bug?

The man-page that I have in front of me says

> The asprintf() and vasprintf() functions set *ret to be a pointer to a
>        buffer sufficiently large to hold the formatted string.  This pointer
>        should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated storage when it is
>        no longer needed.  If sufficient space cannot be allocated, asprintf()
>        and vasprintf() will return -1 and set ret to be a NULL pointer.

In the absense of the the phrase *"set `*ret` to be a pointer to a **new** buffer [...]"*, I am tempted to assume that the function is using `realloc` as `getline` does.

### What might be a problem?

Using the signature `int asprintf(char **ret, const char *format, ...);` for concreteness.

1. `asprintf` runs `realloc` too soon.

   Imagine that we implement the function in such a away that we could run `realloc(*ret)` before it dereferences one of the varargs that aliased the original buffer. That buffer has been freed and this is technically undefined behavior. This would represent a bug.
2. `asprintf` writes into the buffer before it reading it. In the above code we can imaging the function copying the contents of `argv[1]` into `*ret` before it every `va_arg` on the `str` argument. The manpage I quote does not seem to rule this case out.
3. `asprintf` does not `free *ret` either directly or through the use of `realloc`. This would avoid problem number (1) but would leak memory if used as above. Again that man page seems not to rule it out.

### Work around

All of the above could be avoided by replacing the single call to `asprintf` with

```
{
  char *newStr = NULL;
  asprintf(newStr,"%s %s",argv[i],str);
  free(str);
  str = newStr;
}
```

but that is pretty clunky.

**Does the consensus implementation guarantee that the first code sample is safe and correct?**

Comment: By the way, good question. +1.

Comment: `asprintf` is not a standard function, it's a GNU extension. "Is it leaking memory all over the place?" -- Of course it is. The doc says to free the memory, but you don't. `asprintf` cannot possibly `realloc` its first argument -- that's an out parameter and its content cannot be assumed.

Comment: @JimBalter Er...yes. That's right. Thought they are also found in the BSD library that Mac OS uses now. Edits to follow.

Comment: If you pass a non-void pointer to `asprintf` it's overwritten with a call to `malloc`. It doesn't use pre-allocated memory.

Comment: "I am tempted to assume that the function is using realloc as getline does." -- Making such an assumption is completely wrong-headed because the `getline` documentation details how the value of the `lineptr` argument is used. Just compare the documentation and it's obvious that `asprintf` doesn't work the same way ... it never uses the prior value of `*ret`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it leaking memory all over the place?

Yes, it does.

```
char *str = strdup(argv[i]);
```

Here, `str` contains a pointer to `malloc()`ated memory which should be `free()`d.

```
asprintf(&str, "%s %s", argv[i], str);
```

Here, `asprintf()` modifies `str` so that it points to some other memory allocated by the function itself. Now you just lost the pointer to the `strdup()`ped string, hence the leak.

Comment: That depends on weather `asprintf` uses `realloc` (as for instance, `getline` does). It is not clear from the manpage if it *should* or not. Just adding the work "new" in the quoted paragraph above would make this very clear, but without it...

Comment: @dmckee The closest man page I could find is that of OS X. It says: "`asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` dynamically allocate a new string with `malloc(3)`." - so in my opinion, that means resizing the buffer involves calling `realloc()`.

Comment: Must be a newer Mac OS than mine, but that is the word I was looking for. The clunky version it is. *::sigh::*

Comment: @dmckee Yes, unfortunately. The general experience about the C standard library is "it ain't convenient even if it pretends to be"...

Comment: "It is not clear from the manpage if it should or not." -- It's crystal clear from the man page ... you're just doing a very bad job of reading it. "The clunky version it is" -- it would be slightly less clunky if you didn't pointlessly initialize `newstr` to NULL. And `free` is a function -- calling it requires parentheses.

Comment: @dmckee To make the essential point: `ret` is an **out** argument -- `*ret` is set but its value is never used. You can determine this from the documentation because ... it says that `*ret` is set, and never refers to using its value. Thus, `realloc`ing it is out of the question.

Comment: The GNU documentation tends to be better than the man pages: This function is similar to sprintf, except that it dynamically allocates a string (as with malloc; see Section 3.2.2 [Unconstrained Allocation], page 33) to hold the output, instead of putting the output in a buffer you allocate in advance. The ptr argument should be the address of a char * object, and a successful call to asprintf stores a pointer to the newly allocated string at that location.

Comment: @JimBalter I didn't dare questionning OP and I thought I initially misunderstood the question, but really, `realloc()`ing is irrelevant here, isn't it?

Comment: It would be relevant if `asprintf` were like `getline`, which the OP seems to have assumed despite the radically different man pages -- `getline` describes in detail how it reuses the pointed to pointer, with explicit mention of `realloc`, whereas `asprintf` just says that it sets it. The OP seems to want `asprintf` to be tailored to his use case, despite it being uncommon.